# How to use n-grams for multi-label classification?

Tags: nlp, classification, n-gram, language-model

I am working on a project to identify the nationality of the person based on the manner in which they communicate in English. I have 10 nationalities & 1000 files, 100 for each nationality. I am using n-grams as features & looking to validate my approach. My data structure, would have different n-grams (character n-grams, bi-grams, as columns) as features & nationality as labels (as rows) My Steps are :

1. Pick up all files for a given nationality (FINE). 
   1.1. Combine them together to form a text corpus (e.g Combine 100 files into 1 big file). I initially thought for taking one file at a time & updating the count of n-grams based on their occurance. But then for each new n-gram, i would have to do a look up to see if it has already occured & then update its frequency, for a given label. Would this be a better approach ?
2. Extract bi-grams / tri-grams & get frequency of each gram. (NLTK has FreqDist which gives count for each)
3. Store this information, so I would use it to classify my test set. (HOW DO I STORE THIS INFORMATION. MORE INFORMATION BELOW)

Question is should I store the n-gram & frequency information in a matrix (a single matrix having all n-grams & labels OR separate matrix for each label) or should I store it as a map (a map for each label, having n-gram & its frequency count). I would like to have a data structure (for storing the extracted information) that would be easy for classifiers to take as input & process them. I cannot foresee, which data structure would be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

1) it shouldn't matter. if you have a way to do it separately and then merge it, it will help if in the future you want to scale to a distributed system (that's usually called map-reduce approach).

2) ok.

3) n-gram and frequency counts are usually not suitable on their own for feature classification. you probably want to have separate matrices/maps for each label and then use something like TF-IDF (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) to identify n-grams that are characteristic of a particular label.

4) when it comes to classification, you'd then build a fixed-length vector where you select a subset of the ngrams identified for each label in the previous step and then use that for training and classification. you'd probably need some sort of normalization for the counts as well.